# Php include/require file from parent dirs not working

Tags: php, include, directory, require-once

I have the following directory structure:

```
- m
--> css
--> js
--> includes

- php_scripts
```

In my m/includes there is a file called `functions.php` and in my php_scripts there is a file called `conn.php`.
I would like to include the `conn.php`in the `functions.php` file but I have no success with it:

```
<?php
require_once("../../php_scripts/conn.php");
```

I would assume the previous code is correct but it simply doesn't work. Even if there is no other code in functions.php (just the require), the page loads blank. If I check httpfox I see the result 500 - internal server error. If I comment the line with require_once, it works flawlessly. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could check your document root using `?php phpinfo();?` to see if the path is right?

Comment: What's inside the php_scripts/conn.php file? It's getting included, it just has something so wrong that it is causing a 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

try the magic constat "**DIR**":

```
require_once(__DIR__."/../../php_scripts/conn.php");
```